# How can I restrict user to make changes to attachement?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, apex-managed-sharing

I am creating attachment record and I want to restrict user to make any changes to it when he downloads that attachment. Is there any method provided by salesforce to restrict him? or how can I set password to it when creating attachment? or can I make it read only so that user will not be able to edit it. Which approach will help me to complete my requirement?

Comment: How an attachment is treated once it is downloaded has nothing to do with Salesforce. PDF is often used when a file should not be editable but again creating a PDF (except a PDF version of a Visualforce page) is not something that Salesforce can do. All you can do i to stop the attachment being replaced in Salesforce with an edited version via a trigger for specific users/profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control permissions to attachments in that way. You have a couple of options:

a) Create a VF page to show the attachments. Include it in the standard VF page and hide the standard attachment related list (I've done this a few times)

b) Transition to Salesforce Content. This may not apply in most situations but it may in yours. With Content you can do a lot of things that attachments can't.... but there are also things that you can't do that you can with Attachments. Do the research and decide. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can vote up this idea which is view only permission for chatter attachments.. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iWBFAA2